# unexpected error condition deploying war on new WebLogic server

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy a simple war file onto a new WebLogic 12c server on OSX 10.9.4

I installed via the wls1213_devzip_update1.zip and followed the instructions in the ReadMe to configure the new installation.

WebLogic starts without error via ./startWebLogic.sh and I am able to log into the Admin Console.

After following these steps in the Admin Console:
Deploy > Install > upload your files > Choose File > select the war on the file system > Next

After clicking Next, I get the following error in the browser:

> An unexpected error condition has been detected. Details have been recorded in the admin server log

And the following errors in the log:

```
<Feb 1, 2015 6:50:49 AM MST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423147> <Exception [com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ActionLookupFailedException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] thrown while trying to do task [handlePostbackData] in class [com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.PageFlowContent].> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [/com/bea/console/actions/app/install/Flow.jpf].> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI /com/bea/console/actions/app/install/Flow.jpf.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423405> <An exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils] was thrown while rendering the content at [null].> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423137> <There was an error loading the requested URI null.> 
<Feb 1, 2015 6:51:43 AM MST> <Error> <netuix> <BEA-423223> <There was an error while running a lifecycle stage :: Lifecycle: UIControl.render :: for the control :: null ::.>
```

Let me know if there is more info i can provide to help troubleshoot.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing it's the war file that has an issue, not weblogic itself. What war are you uploading when this happens? Does it happen with a different war? You could try one that comes with weblogic in the `wlserver_10.3/samples/server/examples` folder.

Comment: it's not the war.  i get the error when clicking Next after selecting the .war to upload in the console.  there are still several more steps before Finish and deploying the war.  in any case, i just installed wls12120 and did not experience the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs actually tell you what is wrong - the org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils class is missing. I'm not sure why it isn't included in WebLogic but you can get the package which contains this class from the Apache Commons project (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).

I was having the same problem but fixed it by copying commons-io-2.4.jar found in the package to $MW_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib (which appears to house all the other commons jars).

Comment: I agree the logs tells us what is wrong.  Seems like a bug in WebLogic wls1213 since it works without error on wls12120 and really shouldn't be necessary to copy jars into the classpath just to use the console on a fresh WebLogic install.

Comment: hmm...yes, WebLogic does include it's own package in WL_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.bea.core.apache.commons.io_1.2.0.0_1-4.jar. It looks like the FilteringClassLoader is preventing it from being loaded. If I comment out the entry for "org.apache.commons.*" under the prefer-application-packages in WL_HOME/server/lib/consoleapp/META-INF/weblogic-applocation.xml, it works even if I remove the commons-io jar in the consoleapp/APP-INF/lib folder.

Comment: Thanks.  I've accepted the answer since you provide a feasible workaround

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for finding this. We recently updated the version of apache fileupload used by the WLS admin console as part of a security patch, and that introduced a new dependency on commons-io that was lost somewhere in the process. We'll track that down. In the interim, copying the jar to consoleapp/APP-INF/lib is an appropriate workaround (and that's what our fix will be doing.)

I believe that this issue only affects the console's upload feature during deployment. All other features should work as expected.